# (JavaScript) Calculating the angle that is needed for a point to be inside a line

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, trigonometry

[image: Illustration of what I want to achieve]

What I need to code in JavaScript is a function that calculates the angle in degrees, rotated around an origin, that is needed for the point to be positioned on top of a line. A point (as well as the rotation) is defined with the x- and y coordinates. A line is defined with the properties startX, startY, endX, endY.

Thanks for the time and help!

I assume this problem can be solved with trigonometry, but I couldn't figure out how.

The position of the point, the origin or the coordinates of the line are individual. What i want to find is a mathematical implementation of a function like this:

```
function calculateAngle(point, line, rotationOrigin) {
    /* The things i know:
    - point.x, point.y
    - rotationOrigin.x, rotateOrigin.y
    - line.startX, line.startY, line.endX, line.endY
    */
    return angleToFind;
}
```

Comment: Would be awesome if you added everything, or actually, the best code you got so far after your extensive research. Is is Canvas? Plain HTML & CSS? Please read [ask] and [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: the radius of circle is known?  i suppose the angle alpha is the oppositie angle to 90 degree?

Comment: I updated the question. I don't have any code that could be helpful for this. My goal is a function like the one defined in the updated question.

Comment: Why do you need angle marked "alpha"? What is it? Text says about another angle

Comment: @MBo the angle alpha, or whatever to call it, is the angle in degrees i want to find. Its the angle that is needed for the point to be inside the line.

Comment: I suppose you need these angles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN3uq.png rather than unaccountable alpha at your picture

Comment: First thing I would do to simplify it is to calculate all your coordinates from the rotation origin, effectively making that the 'origin'. So, x = point.x - rotationOrigin,x. etc. Then define a function f() of points on the line such that f(0) = startpont, and f(1) = endpoint. Find the distance of those points from the origin |f(lambda)| which needs to be r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2). This gives you the 0, 1, or 2 values of lambda for points on the line. If it's <0 or >1 then it's not between the start and end points of your line.Finally, f(lamda).x = r(sin alpha) and  f(lamda).y = r(cos alpha)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do when asking here is searching here for given answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=circle+line+intersection

[Circle line-segment collision detection algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-segment-collision-detection-algorithm)

[Circle Line Intersection points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053061/circle-line-intersection-points)

To your issue, be aware there can be two solutions (line "secant" to circle), one solution ("tangent"), or none solution (line exterior to circle)

To find the angle, let's say you have the solution "S1(s1x, s1y)". You can form vectors circle-centre to beginning-point and circle-centre to S1.

Again, searching this site:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=angle+between+vectors

you can get that angle. If you use the other solution S2, you get a different angle. You may chose the counter-clockwise one.