# Circle and line segment collision in C#

Tags: c#, geometry, collision-detection

I'm trying to implement a method to check if a circle and a line intersect. I took most of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651248/circle-line-intersection-not-working-properly) code (fixed based on the answer), and also modified the code a bit to use `Point`'s instead of `Vector2f`'s`.

This is currently what I have:

```
private bool CircleLineIntersect(int x, int y, int radius, Point linePoint1, Point linePoint2) {
            Point p1 = new Point(linePoint1.X,linePoint1.Y);
            Point p2 = new Point(linePoint2.X,linePoint2.Y);
            p1.X -= x;
            p1.Y -= y;
            p2.X -= x;
            p2.Y -= y;
            float dx = p2.X - p1.X;
            float dy = p2.Y - p1.Y;
            float dr = (float)Math.Sqrt((double)(dx * dx) + (double)(dy * dy));
            float D = (p1.X * p2.Y)  -  (p2.X * p1.Y);

            float di = (radius * radius) * (dr * dr) - (D * D);

            if (di < 0) return false;
            else return true;
        }
```

It looks consistent with [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html) algorithm, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

If anyone could provide guidance it would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

It doesn't seem to be calculating correctly. For example with input x=1272, y=1809, radius=80, linePoint1={X=1272,Y=2332}, linePoint2={X=1272,Y=2544} there shouldn't be an intersection (y+radius is less than both y values of the line segment), but the function is returning true.

Comment: What IS your problem? In what way does this code not do what you want?

Comment: @Aron It doesn't seem to be calculating correctly. For example with input x=1272, y=1809, radius=80, linePoint1={X=1272,Y=2332}, linePoint2={X=1272,Y=2544} there shouldn't be an intersection (y+radius is less than both y values of the line segment), but the function is returning true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error exists in your test case. Not only does the it intersect, but your line goes through the center of the circle. The line is a vertical line (X =1272). Your circle is centred about (1272, 1809). ERGO it goes through the centre.

Perhaps you have a misunderstanding between the terms line and line-segment, within mathematics.

Comment: I need the function to test for a line segment, not a line. Is there anything I can change to make it test the segment instead of the line? Perhaps testing if the point of intersection is within the line segment?

Comment: I added some code to test if the intersection point lies within the line segment and it seems to work correctly now (although I'm not sure how efficient it is).